# Where's the multiplayer in Clicker Heroes mobile?

Tags: clicker-heroes, mobile

On the [Google Play Page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.r2gamesusa.clickerheroes&hl=en) for Clicker Heroes it talks about multiplayer battles, clans, and the like.

I've been playing for a little while (up to high 70s in the floors and getting ready to ascend), but these multiplayer options have not appeared yet.

When does multiplayer appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cross zone 135](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Clans) on mobile to unlock the clan tab. This is different from the desktop or browser version's zone 50 requirement.